# Change border color of CComboBox to show error and warning

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, activex, controls, ccombobox

I am using CComboBox in my project. I want to change the color of the border combo box on focus

Comment: For background color, I can advise you to see documentation about `OnCtlColor`

Comment: @sergiol I have checked it is not working

Comment: Show your code, what you have trying.

Comment: Use Spy++ to check what messages are passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Finally it is done and it has a very easy solution.
I just overridden the onpaint method of the control.

```
void CComboBoxOwn::OnPaint()
{
CDC *dc = m_Parent->combobox->GetDC();
CRect rc; 
m_Parent->combobox->GetClientRect(rc);
HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(COLORREF(RGB(255, 0, 0)));
FrameRect(dc->m_hDC, rc, hBrush);
DeleteObject(hBrush);
ReleaseDC(dc);

return;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look right. Painting should always use a `CPaintDC`. Besides that, it is completely unclear, what `m_Parent` is, or its `combobox` member for that matter. This answer is not generally useful, sorry.

Comment: CComboboxown is my class where m_parent is the member variable of CComboCntl class.